# dequeueReusableCell causing weird behavior

Tags: ios

i'am creating an iOS application which is similar to bbc application
- I have a table view which has two section
- 1st section contains cells containing scrollview wid images
- 2nd section contains expandable cells which contains scrollview did images
so the  problem is that
when i use the dequereusable its showing weird behaviors like when the bottommost cell in the table is expanded the first cell in the first gets cleared etc etc
so i have just stopped using the queue and everything started working fine
but now when i added images after scrolling the cells which is not in the view gets refreshed and its
taking a lot of time to load

so could kindly guide me how to use the queue wisely in the code
described below
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

```
NSString *CellIdentifier=@"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell== nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"hai"] autorelease];
```

///[here a different name has been used for the reuse identifier];////

```
      if ([self tableView:tableView inSection2:indexPath.section]) {
        Coffee *co =[appDelegate.coffeeArray2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section-s1Count-1];
         cell.textLabel.text=co.coffeeName;

    }

    if ([self tableView:tableView inSection1:indexPath.section]) {

        Coffee *co =[appDelegate.coffeeArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        cell.textLabel.text = co.coffeeName;
        CGRect cellname = CGRectMake(5, 0, 290, 25);
        UILabel *cellabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cellname] autorelease];

        cellabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        cellabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:20];

        cellabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];

        cellabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor clearColor];

       cellabel.text=co.coffeeName;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellabel];


    }


// Configure the cell...

if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section]) 

{
    if (!indexPath.row)

    {     

        // first row

       // only top row showing



        if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])

        {

            cell.accessoryView = [myuicontroller accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];

        }

        else

        {

            cell.accessoryView = [myuicontroller accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];

        }





    }

    else

    {

        // all other rows

        cell.accessoryView = nil;    

        cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


        CGRect cellname = CGRectMake(5, 0, 290, 25);

        UILabel *cellabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cellname] autorelease];

        cellabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        cellabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:13];

        cellabel.textColor=[UIColor blueColor];

        cellabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor clearColor];

       // cellabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"category"];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellabel];

        myscrollView *svb;
           svb=[[myscrollView alloc]initwitharray:appDelegate.newscat1];

}else{

    myscrollView *s;

    NSLog(@"inside the textlabel ext%@",cell.textLabel.text);

    NSLog(@"count of array  %d",[appDelegate.newscat1 count]);

    NSString *cat=cell.textLabel.text;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:s];

}

}   



return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the alternative reuse identifier *before* you dequeue the cell. At the moment you are dequeuing a cell with identifier "cell" regardless of the section you are in, so you will often be returning a section 0 cell for a section 1 part of the table.

So, branch your code so that you do different things depending on the value of `indexPath.section`:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
    cellIdentifier = @"thisCell";
else
    cellIdentifier = @"otherCell";
```

Then dequeue your cell, if it is nil, create with the same cell identifier variable above.

You should only be adding subviews inside your (cell = nil) code - otherwise you will end up with cells with lots of overlapping subviews and will be wasting memory. If a cell has been dequeued, you just configure the existing subviews, you don't make new ones. You can assign tags to your subviews as you add them to assist with this.

Comment: now there is a new problem the change in the data source is not getting reflected when i reload the table but when i remove the dequeue the change is reflected.is there a way to remove the old data in the dequeue?

Comment: If there is a new problem, ask a new question.